# Any hopster like free application on mac to bypass firewall?

Tags: macos, mac, firewall

On windows, hopster can be used to bypass firewall , then can use msn , or gtalk freely.

But on mac, what is the similar application and it is free ?

Comment: Hard- or Software firewall?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of HTTP tunneling software available out there for Mac. [Barracuda](http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/HttpsTunnel.lsp) springs to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a bunch of different solutions to get passed traffic filtering firewalls.  The fastest (i.e. the one that allows me the most available bandwidth) is [HotSpot Shield](http://anchorfree.com/downloads/hotspot-shield/), but it introduces annoying ads on every webpage I visit.  Some other ones I've tried that are far less intrusive but aren't great for downloading large files over are:

- [UltraVPN](https://www.ultravpn.fr/) (requires
  [Tunnelblick](http://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/) client on OSX)
- [JAP](http://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/index_en.html)